# CSS On Hover Fade in Another Div

Tags: css

```css
.currently_playing {
 float:left;
 width:250px;
 height:450px;
}
.currently_playing .cover {
 float: left;
 margin: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
 height: 210px;
 width: 210px;
 position: relative;
}
.currently_playing .cover img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.currently_playing .cover .controls {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.currently_playing .cover .controls:hover {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.currently_playing .cover .controls .scale {
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%; left: 50%;
 margin:-15px 0 0 -15px;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 background:url(http://i743.photobucket.com/albums/xx78/MrTIMarshall2512/artwork_scale_zps1ztoz3qv.png) no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.currently_playing .cover .controls:hover .scale {
 display:block;
 -webkit-transition: all 4.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 4.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 4.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 4.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="currently_playing">
    <div class="cover">
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="scale"></div>
        </div>
        <img src="http://www.at40.com/cimages/var/plain_site/storage/images/repository/news/music-news/new-album-art-released-for-bruno-mars-unorthodox-jukebox/224005-1-eng-US/New-Album-Art-Released-For-Bruno-Mars-Unorthodox-Jukebox.jpg" alt="Bruno Mars, Unorthodox Jukebox album artwork">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've currently got this working so that upon hovering over the album artwork, it will appear to darken with an ease effect, however the scale button just simply appears and visa-versa hovering out.

Is there a way to make it so that upon hovering over, the scale element appears to fade in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display none doesn't animate use opacity

```css
.currently_playing {
 float:left;
 width:250px;
 height:450px;
}
.currently_playing .cover {
 float: left;
 margin: 20px 20px 5px 20px;
 height: 210px;
 width: 210px;
 position: relative;
}
.currently_playing .cover img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.currently_playing .cover .controls {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  opacity: 0;
}
.currently_playing .cover .controls:hover {
   opacity: 1;
}
.currently_playing .cover .controls .scale {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%; left: 50%;
 margin:-15px 0 0 -15px;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 background:url(http://i743.photobucket.com/albums/xx78/MrTIMarshall2512/artwork_scale_zps1ztoz3qv.png) no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="currently_playing">
    <div class="cover">
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="scale"></div>
        </div>
        <img src="http://www.at40.com/cimages/var/plain_site/storage/images/repository/news/music-news/new-album-art-released-for-bruno-mars-unorthodox-jukebox/224005-1-eng-US/New-Album-Art-Released-For-Bruno-Mars-Unorthodox-Jukebox.jpg" alt="Bruno Mars, Unorthodox Jukebox album artwork">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this!